# Incorrect URL Construction, need HTAccess Redirect Fix

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard, redirect

I've made a huge mistake in my shop when creating pagination links. After the .html, instead of a question mark my code just appended an ampersand. Now Google Webmaster tools is throwing up hundreds of 404's.

I know how to fix the problem on a URL by URL basis, but is there a wildcard solution as a first off sanity check in HTAccess to check for ".html&" and replace with ".html?"?

Below are examples of my issue, myitemspage represents a category of items, so i have over 50 categories:

```
http://www.domain.com/myitemspage.html&page=1&limitchange=10
http://www.domain.com/myitemspage.html&page=1&limitchange=25
http://www.domain.com/myitemspage.html&page=1&limitchange=50
http://www.domain.com/myitemspage.html&page=1&limitchange=100
```

Thank you for any help on my self-created nightmare,

Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\.html&(.*)$ /$1.html?$2
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html&(.*)$ /$1.html?$2 [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Is there a method to just accept any ".html&" and replace with ".html?" URL, regardless of pagename as I don't want to add this piece of code for every category webpage page in the shop?

Comment: @user2569395 just get rid of the `^myitemspage` part of the regex

Comment: Thank you again, and I assume the "/myitemspage.html" is changed to "/^?$1"?

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.". I will have a play around and try to pin down the problem. Many thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: @user2569395 Do you have mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: I believe I do as I use other rewrite conditions such as "Remove index.php or index.htm/html from URL requests".

Comment: Worked like a dream after I removed an invalid 301 line elsewhere. Great work, thank you so much. +1.